# How to get a clean YouTube transcript

Tags: python, youtube, timestamp, data-cleaning, subtitle

I am trying to get video subtitle data, for that I am using downsub.

There is no way I have figured out to get clean subtitle, without HTML tags and timestamps, without taking it to notepad and doing replace procedure as appropriate.

This is cumbersome and I want to automate the cleaning process using python.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bbgbjbGF9bjzz3FISMfycSW4iHCj3pxk

I am looking for a really really simple solution that anyone can comprehend with just basic knowledge of Python. I'm open to using the API if need be, but if this takes long, manual cleaning is still only taking a few minutes if done quickly. Automation would be nice though; would relieve a headache. With this considered, please propose a good and nice solution.

Comment: if it is simple enough that you can replace html stuff in a notepad manually, could you perhaps do the replacements automatically? such as `html_string.replace('<div>', ''))`

Comment: btw the link needs permissioning to access

Comment: @Zulfiqaar: Thanks, I've updated sharing: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bbgbjbGF9bjzz3FISMfycSW4iHCj3pxk

Comment: @ParitoshSingh parser, noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have made a few changes to the replacement, but this should do it:

```
import requests

down_url = "https://downsub.com/index.php?title=5+Am+Club+by+Robin+Sharma+%7C%7C+Review%2C+Takeaways+and+Discussion&url=ujcNaH9TaDy8U56iM_1ZReCKk1h83rjIvE7i146GYHUNIwZwKM02q9oUSieWkZ47Tw2OOJgFBvlU0he-sxkGIASxRnTcdMwE1QrZ3CAsyI5gLS6A0ovxFMmFJx5EAC5wtwexy0R1vzZfNdt6dBse3H-vOhq8xnqL-LdhSbiePZ5E_KEYrYuFzPvF2JpEARuCOA6XlqQQzV7iooSEObb9AejBkNj_uHhNnO0RVJ0E-pVAJjWLdjUnIdXGPkJUsd5Ceg5qeTVKjtBQhWyf6qCuwE_BAezDSDAF6DgLCFRnwc2Uc9onnorwYncvzIge1soln3FnkifpyHiPB3cK0h0f5yMUy-DJHervcQXQEHdUf-npkCzRgeba283yoN7orAovE0iaIihvFMectGYKT27eXLdrLdQQ3sUcWFqRB6SjZ8g"

data = requests.get(down_url).text


clean = ['<font color="#CCCCCC">',
         '<font color="#E5E5E5">',
         '<font color="#EEE">',
         '</font>',
         0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
         '::, --> ::,',]


for s in clean:
    data = data.replace(str(s), '')

data = data.replace('\n\n\n\n', '\n')

print(data)
```

Comment: This works :) 
Thank you. I've updated the notebook.

Comment: no problem - and its the first im hearing of downsub, which might come in handy later for me too!